# CruiseControl Remote Dashboard Access

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

Sorry if this is kind of a noob question, but I'm just starting to use CruiseControl, and I'd like to allow access to the DashBoard from anywhere on the internet.

I can't find any documentation on how to do this. I'm running it off of a Windows machine, and I can start CC and view the DashBoard through http://localhost:8080/

Any ideas?

**Update:** I added a new Inbound rule for my machine on 8080, however http://canyouseeme.org/ says it's not open. Strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any special action is needed to allow external access, so I think your problem is more of a general web hosting problem than it is specific to CruiseControl.  Here are a few things that might be worth looking at:

- Make sure your firewall is not blocking access to the port.
- Make sure your network's domain policy allows external access to your computer.
- Are you starting CruiseControl from the command line or as a service?  If starting from the command line, try starting it as a service and see if the results are different.  How to do this depends on your system configuration, but usually, if you are using CruiseControl .NET, run the command `net start "CruiseControl.Net Server"`.  If you are using standard CruiseControl, run `net start "CruiseControl Service"`.

Comment: I think you're right. How do I start it as a service? I've been invoking it over the command line. Also, edited my post to add some more information.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include notes on starting the service.

Comment: Hm. Still fails for me, though I'm pretty sure you're right. I'll try it on another machine.

Comment: Agreed.  If an machine on the outside can't see that port, the problem probably isn't CruiseControl.  Good luck!